# $\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^p}$ series convergence check

Tags: sequences-and-series

Check for which $p$ functional series $\sum {\sin(nx) \over n^{p}}$ converges.
It is easy to see that for any p > 1 it does converge for any real x. Because of comparsion test. How to figure out other cases? Maybe just show that $\lim {\sin(nx) \over n^{p}}$ is not $0$ for some p(for them series won't converge).

Comment: Use the Dirichlet test of convergence for $0<p\le1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First one may observe that as $x = \pm0,\pm \pi\pm2 \pi,\ldots $ the given series vanishes, then it is **convergent**.

- Assume $p\leq0$. Then, for all $x \neq \pm0,\pm \pi\pm2 \pi,\ldots $,
  $$ \lim_{n \to \infty}
         \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^{p}} \neq 0 $$ and the given series is
     **divergent**.
- Assume $0<p\leq 1$. Then, one may apply the [Dirichlet test of
     convergence of series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet's_test), $n \mapsto \dfrac1{n^{p}}$ is decreasing
     tending to $0$, and for all $x \neq \pm0,\pm \pi\pm2 \pi,\ldots $,
     we have  $$ \left|\sum_{n=1}^N\sin(nx)\right|=\left|\Im\sum_{n=1}^N
     e^{inx}\right|=\left|\Im\:\frac{e^{ix}(1-e^{iNx})}{1-e^{ix}}\right|\leq
     \frac2{\left|1-e^{ix}\right|}<\infty, $$ and the given series is
     **convergent**.

Comment: I understand by intuition, why limit of sin(nx)/n^p when p<=0 is not 0. But do not know how to formalize it easily.

Comment: Take $x:=\frac\pi2$, then $\lim_{p \to \infty}\sin(4p\pi/2)=0$ whereas $\lim_{p \to \infty}\sin((4p+1)\pi/2)=1\neq0$, thus neither $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sin(nx)$ does exist nor $\lim_{n \to \infty}n^{|p|}\sin(nx)$ does exist.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you generalize the statement for any real x, not only for x=pi/2.What theorem do you use?

Comment: It is always possible to extract two subsequences from $\sin(nx)$ with *different* limits as above, and multiplying by $n^{|p|}$ doesn't help.