# Convergence of sum of $\frac{\sin(nx)}{n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am very curious about the convergence of the series $\displaystyle \sum\frac{\sin(nx)}{n+1}$, where $x$ is a real number. I know the trivial cases, like $x=0$, but have no idea about how to solve for non-trivial ones (without using Dirichlet criteria)

Comment: Dirichlet's test: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test See e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795021/frac-sinnxnp-series-convergence-check for a very similar series

Comment: Oops yeah, I know Dirichlet criteria, forgot to mention I would like to know a way without using it (edited now)

Comment: Also try alternating series test since the sine is alternating, so you can write it in complex form.

Comment: $\sum a_n \sin(nx)$ converges whenever $a_n$ decreases to $0$. Ref. p. 112 of Fourier Series by Edwards.

Comment: But it isnt completely alternating, consecutive terms need not be of opposite sign, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out yesterday from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yf7Aq0dqZNk) that we can prove, using some basic complex analysis, that $\ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(n x)}{n}\ $ converges for all $\ x.\ $ Interestingly, it converges to exactly $\ \frac{\pi - x}{2}.$

Unfortunately we **cannot** now use the [Limit Comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $$\ \frac{\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}}{\frac{\sin(nx)}{n+1}} = \frac{n+1}{n}\overset{n\to\infty}{\to} 1 >0,$$

because the limit comparison test requires $\ \frac{\sin(nx)}{n}\ \geq 0\ $ and $\ \frac{\sin(nx)}{n} \geq 0\ \ \forall\ n\ $ which is not true.

However, we can use [Abel's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_test) [which I have never used before, so this is exciting!] with $\ a_n = \frac{\sin(nx)}{n}\ $ and $\ b_n = \frac{n}{n-1}\ \left(= 1-\frac{1}{n-1}\right)\ $ which is monotone and bounded, and so Abel's test works here:

$$\sum a_n b_n =  \sum\frac{\sin(nx)}{n+1}\ $$

converges.