# Determine the convergence of Fourier series and find the function to which it converges

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

I am suppose to determine the Fourier series of a piecewise-defined function $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in [0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x\in [\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi)$ and find out if this Fourier series converges to what function (if it actually converges).

I started with computing my series and obtained $$F = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\pi}{2k}(\cos(kx) + \sin (kx)).$$

The **first question** arise here: since the period of my function is $[0,\pi]$ instead of a $2\pi$ period, I computed my Fourier coefficients with slightly adjusted formulas $$a_0 = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^\pi f(x)dx, \quad a_k = \frac{\pi}{2} \int_0^\pi f(x)\cos(kx)dx, \quad  b_k = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi f(x)\sin(kx)dx$$ in which I am not sure if I should make these adjustments for $a_k$ and $b_k$.

Then it comes to **determining the convergence**; I looked up another Fourier post on StackExchange and the answer suggested finding the periodic extension.

However my class readings or lectures did not really cover or mention anything related to periodic extension, and I am wondering if there is another way to determine the convergence and find the function?

Comment: Once you write a trigonometric polynomial (which is what the Fourier series is) on $[0, 2\pi)$, you can extend it periodically in a very natural way. For determining the convergence (without explicing the limit) you can see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795021/frac-sinnxnp-series-convergence-check .

Comment: You may compute the sum as $$
\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{\pi }{{2k}}\cos (kx)}  = \frac{\pi }{4}\Re \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{e^{ikx} }}{k}}  = \frac{\pi }{4}\Re \log \left( {\frac{1}{{1 - e^{ix} }}} \right) =  - \frac{\pi }{8}\log (2 - 2\cos x),$$ and similarly for the sine part.